# Laravel - Como sobrescrever a mensagem da validação?

Tags: laravel, validação

Tenho uma Request que faz validações através de uma classe `Request`:

O Controller:

```
  public function store(PagtoRequest $request)
  {
   ... resto da lógica
```

A Request:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;


use App\Rules\ValidarValor;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;


class PagtoRequest extends FormRequest
{
  public function authorize()
  {
    return true;
  }



  public function rules(Request $request)
  {

    $arrayParcelas = $request->input("arrayParcelas"); // guardando no dados das percelas


    return [
      'arrayParcelas.*.vcto_parcela' => ['required','date_format:"d/m/Y"'], // verifica se as datas informadas são válidas
      'arrayParcelas.*.valor_parcela' => ['required',new ValidarValor], // verifica se os valores informados são válidos
    ];
  }

  public function messages() {
    return [
      'arrayParcelas.*.vcto_parcela.date_format' => 'Existem parcelas com datas inválidas',
      'arrayParcelas.*.valor_parcela.ValidarValor' => 'Existem parcelas com valores inválidos',
    ];
  }
}
```

A Rule:

```
namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ValidarValor implements Rule
{
  public function __construct()
  {

  }

  public function passes($attribute, $value)
  {
    // verifica se está no formato 9.999.999.999,99 e quantos milhares forem necessários.
    $expressao = "/^([1-9]{1}[\d]{0,2}(\.[\d]{3})*(\,[\d]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[\d]{0,}(\,[\d]{0,2})?|0(\,[\d]{0,2})?|(\,[\d]{1,2})?)$/";
    return (preg_match($expressao,$value));
  }

  public function message()
  {
    return "O campo :attribute está no formato incorreto.";
  }
}
```

A primeira regra, eu consigo personalizar a mensagem de erro, pois uso uma regra de validação do Laravel (no caso da validação do campo `vcto_parcela`)

Mas no caso onde uso a `Rule` `ValidarValor`, como personalizar a mensagem?

Da forma que fiz, não funciona, pois está retornando ao mensagem da Rule ao invés da mensagem que eu defini na Request.

Ou seja, (exemplificando caso uma das parcelas estiver no formato incorreto) está retornando esta mensagem (vindo da `Rule`):

> `O campo arrayParcelas.2.valor_parcela está no formato incorreto.`

Ao invés desta, que eu defini na `Request`:

> `Existem parcelas com valores inválidos.`

Com certeza, isso é porque isto não está certo:

```
'arrayParcelas.*.valor_parcela.ValidarValor' => 'Existem parcelas com valores inválidos',
```

Mas como fazer então para que exiba a mensagem de erro que eu defini, quando uso uma Rule?

Comment: Não merece voto negativo, outro voto negativo dado sem sentido

Comment: Poste a request inteira @blur

Comment: tira o Request do método `public function rules(Request $request)` deixando como o padrão `public function rules()`?

Comment: Editei a pergunta com todas as informações

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Analisando o código e o que o [laravel](/questions/tagged/laravel) nos [proporciona para validar dados com classes customizadas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation) o que você fez é assim mesmo ou seja, funciona dessa forma, ***claro que tem como contornar*** podendo adicionar funcionalidades a essa classe para que quando for passado uma mensagem no seu `constructor` possa ter a opção de usar uma nova ***mensagem de validação***, ***exemplo***:

```
<?php namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ValidarValor implements Rule
{
    private $message;
    public function __construct($message = null)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $expressao = "/^([1-9]{1}[\d]{0,2}(\.[\d]{3})*(\,[\d]{0,2})?|[1-9]{1}[\d]{0,}(\,[\d]{0,2})?|0(\,[\d]{0,2})?|(\,[\d]{1,2})?)$/";
        return (preg_match($expressao,$value));
    }
    public function message()
    {
        return $this->message ?? 'O campo :attribute está no formato incorreto.';
    }
}
```

com essa mudança feita no seu `contructor` agora tem a possibilidade de mudar a mensagem padrão da sua regra da seguinte forma:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Rules\ValidarValor;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

    class PagtoRequest extends FormRequest
    {
        public function authorize()
        {
            return true;
        }
        public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'valor_parcela' => [
                    'required', 
                     new ValidarValor('Existem parcelas com valores inválidos') // passe aqui !!!
                ]
            ];
        }

        public function messages()
        {
            // remova somente aquele validação que foi customizada na classe
            return [

            ];
        }
    }
```

<sup>***Referencias***</sup>

- [Laravel - Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation)
- [How to override the message of the custom validation rule in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56384220/how-to-override-the-message-of-the-custom-validation-rule-in-laravel)

Comment: Perfeito. Muito bom. Obrigado!